# Understanding Projection for Near tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, proximity, geodesic

I need to find the nearest distance of points from points in ArcMap. Both layers are in WGS 1984.

When I choose geodesic distance in Near tool, I get results in meters.

I don't do any projection.

Is this wrong?

Comment: That is correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. 
So when and why people do projection before finding the distance in meters?

Comment: You probably want to review what geodesic distance means.